# Dependencies conflict using jest

Tags: react-testing-library

I am new to jest testing with react hooks compnent.I install jest,@testing-library/react,@testing-library/user-event,react-rerender, and react-dom on my Project but i am paining with react-hooks error. for sure it is version difference  but i need help on that.lets list the versions i have installed

1.nodejs:v14.16.0 (i can't change this as the Project request) b/c of this i can't upgread react to latest.
2.react and react-dom:"^16.10.1",
3. "jest-environment-jsdom": "^26.6.3",
4,"jest": "^26.6.3",
=> so My question  is here what are the main dependency  and Pre-dependence  versions must i have to focus  on to solve the error below.

here is the error:
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: